# dynamically created button hide in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have created button using this:

```
$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($e))
{   

    echo '<td><img src="'.$path.$row['photo'].'" border="0" width=100 height=50/></td>';
    echo $row['fname'];
    echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"send request\" name=\"$i\" onclick=\"sendreq('".$row['uname']."')\"/>";
    //echo $i;
    echo "<br/>";
    $i=$i+1;
}
```

and passing the `username` `onclick` of the button through `sendreq()` function.This is `javascript` function. I just want to hide this button when `sendreq()` job is done.

Comment: just hide or completely remove it from DOM?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the javascript to assign is the `display:none;` CSS attribute, though I am uncertain whether it would have to be applied to an encapsulating div or whether it would work directly on the image itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($e))
{   

    echo '<td><img src="'.$path.$row['photo'].'" border="0" width=100 height=50/>
          </td>';
    echo $row['fname'];
    echo "<input id='btnSubmit' type=\"button\" value=\"send request\" name=\"$i\" 
          onclick=\"sendreq('".$row['uname']."');   
          document.GetElementById('btnSubmit').hide(); \"/>";
    //echo $i;
    echo "<br/>";
    $i=$i+1;
}
```

after the method is executed, the element will hide.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line at the end of the function.

```
  <script>
    jQuery("#btnSubmit").hide();
 </script>
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

edit your input button tag like this 
assign a id to button (such as i used remove as id here) and add this code on last of the function sendreg

```
document.getElementById("remove").style.display='none';
```

or use jquery functions like

```
$("#remove").hide();
```

or `$("#remove").fadeOut(3000);`